# Using malloc properly

Tags: c, unix, getcwd

I'm trying to put my directory pathname on a string variable, like this:

```
int main(int ac, char **av)
{
  char*dir;

  if(ac > 2)
    {
      dir = malloc(sizeof(*dir) * 512);
      getcwd(dir, sizeof(*dir));
      printf("dat dir is:\n");
      printf("%s\n", dir);
    }
}
```

I got a blank printed, but when I do something like that

```
int main(int ac, char **av)
{
  char dir[512];

  if(ac > 2)
    {
      // dir = malloc(sizeof(dir) * 512);                                                                
      getcwd(dir, sizeof(dir));
      printf("dat dir is:\n");
      printf("%s\n", dir);
    }
}
```

it is printed properly, why? Isn't my first malloc suppose to make my variable like dir[512]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In

```
getcwd(dir, sizeof(*dir))
```

the `sizeof` is producing a 1 because `*dir` refers to a single `char`.  This isn't what you want.  If you replace this with 512, all ought to work fine.

The idiomatic coding would be something like this:

```
int main(int ac, char **av)
{
  const int buf_size = 512;
  char *dir;

  if(ac > 2)
    {
      dir = malloc(buf_size);
      getcwd(dir, buf_size);
      printf("dat dir is:\n");
      printf("%s\n", dir);
    }
}
```

Note multiplying by `sizeof(*dir)` is a no-op because it always returns 1.  That is, `malloc` allocates in units of `char`.  So I've omitted the no-op.

Comment: i put 512, it worked thanks, is 512 enough on unix ? and also why it is not printing the first character of the path if its 1 ?

Comment: This varies by system. For Linux it is apparently 4096. See http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/include/linux/limits.h?v=2.6.11.8.  But I'm not an expert on Linux.

Comment: When the size is 1, the only thing `getcwd()` can do is put the null terminator in the string.  When it's 0, it can't even do that.

Answer (score 2):

It has to do with arrays, pointers and the meaning of `sizeof`.

```
char dir[512];
sizeof(dir);
```

This is asking for the size of an array, which in this case is `sizeof(char) * 512` -> `512`.

```
char *dir;
sizeof(dir);
```

This is asking for the size of a pointer, which in this case is `sizeof(char *)` -> `4` or `8`

```
char *dir;
sizeof(*dir);
```

This is an odd construct. I really don't feel comfortable with it. Because `dir` has not been initialized any dereferncing of `dir` is cause for concern. But I think the compiler is working out the correct thing here, which in this case is `sizeof(char)` -> `1`.

When working if pointers, you need to carry around the size which you allocated.

```
char*dir;
if(ac > 2)
{
    dir = malloc(sizeof(char) * 512);
    getcwd(dir, sizeof(char) * 512);
    printf("dat dir is:\n");
    printf("%s\n", dir);
}
```

The right answer™ is a bit more complicated.

```
if (ac > 2)
{
    size_t size = 512;
    char *buf = malloc(size);
    char *dir = getcwd(buf, size);

    while (dir == NULL && errno == ERANGE)
    {
        size *= 2;
        buf = realloc(buf, size);
        dir = getcwd(buf, size);
    }

    printf("dat dir is:\n");
    printf("%s\n", dir);
    free(buf);
}
```

First thing, I drop `sizeof(char)`. In C, `sizeof(char)` is defined to be `1`, so it's redundant. Next, set `dir` as the return value of `getcwd(3)` and keep the data buffer separate. Be sure to check the return value, if `getcwd(3)` returns `NULL` and `errno` is `ERANGE` then `buf` was not big enough. In my example, I double the size of the buffer before trying `getcwd(3)` again. Finally, don't forget to free `buf`.

The thing I'm not doing here is checking the return value of `malloc(3)` or `realloc(3)`. This is because I feel there is not point in this example. If I can't allocate the size of a path, then my program is going to crash no matter what I do.

Answer (score 0):

Less things to go wrong if you put the size into a variable early on and then use that:

```
    {
      const sizeof_dir = sizeof(*dir)*512;
      dir = malloc(sizeof_dir);                                                                
      getcwd(dir, sizeof_dir);
      printf("dat dir is:\n");
      printf("%s\n", dir);
    }
```

What killed you was `getcwd(dir, sizeof(*dir))`, where the sizeof was still 1.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you dynamically allocates memory then always check the return value from calloc, malloca and realloc, because return value indicates that memory allocated successfully or not. Here the aforesaid first answer is good and to check the returned value is always helpful.